# Checking for Presence of Negative List Characters Using Java Pattern

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching, user-input

I seem to have been caught with the incorrect useage of expression at run time. The line that has been causing the heart burn is

```
String expression = "$+!*'(),{}|\^[]`<>#%";/?:&=";
```

This is my code

```
public static boolean hasBlackListCharacters(CharSequence strString)
{
    boolean hasBlackListedChar = false;

    String expression = "$+!*'(),{}|\^[]`<>#%";/?:&=";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(expression, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(strString);
    if (matcher.matches()) {
        hasBlackListedChar = true;
    }


    return hasBlackListedChar;
}
```

The Input should not match any of the following characters.

```
$+!*'(),{}|\^[]`<>#%";/?:&=
```

Input String

```
<img src = "http://evil.com">
```

The `CharSequence` has to be searched for presence of any of these characters.. and return or false accordingly.

Comment: What did you try? `xxxxxxxxxx` seems to be a placeholder for something that you must have tried.

Comment: I highly recommend using this online tool to develop your own regex and test it with many inputs http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html

Comment: $+!*'(),{}|\^[]`<>#%";/?:&= I guess something is wrong with this.. Improper Escaping characters?

Comment: This regex expression: `[^8]` will accept anything other than `8`

Comment: @Multithreader - Did check out regexplanet. No joy. Didn't get your comment about [^8]

Comment: I'm aware there are 12 characters that need to be escaped... $+*(){}[]\^? Even if I update the expression string to "[*\$\+!\*'\(\),\{\}\|\\\^\[\]`<>#%";\/\?:&=]" I don't seem to be getting a confirmation indicating presence of a character from negative list

Comment: I was going to post an answer using `Pattern.quote`, thinking it would escape all the special characters.  But I checked the code and `Pattern.quote` doesn't work like that--it uses `\\Q` and `\\E`.  (I think I was thinking of a Perl function that works like I was hoping.)  Is there some other JRE method that will put backslashes before all special characters, so that they can be used in a character class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private static Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[$+!*'(),{}|\\\\^\\[\\]`<>#%\";/?:&=]");

public static boolean hasBlackListCharacters(String strString) {
    return pattern.matcher(strString).find();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String expression = "$+!*'(),\\{\\}|\\\\^\\[\\]`<>#%\";/?:&=";
```

You need to escape backslash twice as it is inside a regex to make it a regex escape and not java excape
\ becomes \\

Escape the curly braces to avoid illegal repetition near index exception

Escape the square brackets.

You can also look into, 
https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeJava(java.lang.String)
This class has powerful escaping features.